# Regarding for loop in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I gave the input `0` `1` `5` , the answer should be `5` but it is not showing me `...`,
help me out with the syntax

```
    a, b, c = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    ans = None
    for i in range(3,c):
        ans=a + (b*b)
        a=b
        b=ans
        print ans
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop will run twice for i = 3, and i = 4.

The first run:

```
ans = 0 + 1 * 1 #1
a = 1
b = 1
print(1)
```

The second run:

```
ans = 1 + 1 * 1 # 2
a = 1
b = 2
print(2)
```

Now `ans` is 2. It's not clear why you think it should be 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
a, b, c = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
ans = None
for i in range(2,c):
    ans=a + (b*b)
    a=b
    b=ans
print (ans)
```

Note that `for i in range(2,c)` i will be 2 then 3 and then 4. It will not be 5 (=c) it stops at c-1.

Edit: if you just want the loop to run c times you can say `for i in range(c)`. This way it will run for i=0,1,2,...,c-1.

Comment: then what to use for making the loop go upto c

Comment: When you say for i in range (3,5) i is going to be 3,4. So if you want i to go from 3 to c you have to write:
for i in range(3,c+1). So if c is 5 this will run for i 3,4,5.

Answer (score 0):

As per Python 3, print command syntax is 
`print('your text')
print(variable)
print('your text ans: ',ans)`
Without semi-circular brackets print won't work.
Refer: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html